# How to add an add to cart button on products displayed on product recommendation section in shopify?

Tags: shopify, product, liquid, shopify-template

i'm using dawn theme, and i tried adding button to the product-card.liquid file, here the code..

```
{% for image in product.images limit:1 %}
   <a href="{{ product_card_product.url | default: '#' }}">
     <img src="{{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: '533x' }}" />
   </a>
{% endfor %}    
<form method="post" action="/cart/add" style="text-align: center">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" />
       <button type="submit" class="addCart" {% unless product.available %} disabled="disabled" {% endunless %}>
       {% unless product.available %}
           {{ "products.product.sold_out" | t }}
       {% else %}
           {{ "products.product.add_to_cart" | t }}
       {% endunless %}
       </button>
    </form>
```

so what happens is, this particular section is in product page, and by clicking on add to cart button, this adds up that particular product page's product, which already has a dedicated button and doesn't add the product which is recommended..
i tried printing the product.variants.first.id object beside add to cart, and this id is same for all the products recommended..
i have checked all the for loops and everythings closed and proper..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **product_card_product** as object instead of **product**

```
  <form method="post" action="/cart/add" style="text-align: center">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product_card_product.variants.first.id }}" />
    <button type="submit" class="addCart" {% unless product_card_product.available %} disabled="disabled" {% endunless %}>
      {% unless product_card_product.available %}
      {{ "products.product.sold_out" | t }}
      {% else %}
      {{ "products.product.add_to_cart" | t }}
      {% endunless %}
    </button>
  </form>
```